# It is safe to store celery in aluminum foil?

Tags: storage-method, celery

Because I cannot find on a regular basis celery, I am trying to preserve what I buy as long as possible.

After trying some methods, the one I found is aluminum foil.
I wash the celery, dry it, put in paper towels, then in aluminum foil, then put in the vegetables area of the freezer.
I managed to have fresh celery for 2 weeks, maximum, keeping in mind I didn't use a metal knife for cutting the edges.

Is it safe to store celery in aluminum foil?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's safe.  It's not acidic, and thus won't corrode the foil or cause it to leach in.

Personally, my favorite was to store celery is in the crisper, in a vented tupperware container, lightly moistened.  This extends lifetime somewhat.

Comment: It sounds like the OP's storage method is functionally similar to yours - mostly covered, and maybe a little bit moistened despite having been dried.

Answer (score 3):

My experience with aluminum foil storage is usually limited to meat product. Our family always wrap vegetables in newspaper to increase their shelf life. Occasionally we slightly dampen or re-dampen the newspaper to extend the preservation period. People say newspapers retain moisture of the vegetables while allowing them to "breath", hence increasing the storage time. It does work fine, and I don't notice any health effect.

Answer (score 1):

Mainly kinds of aluminum foil products are make by food grade material now, especially such made from **food grade 8011 alloy**. It's harmless to food and safe to human body, so don't worry about that.